# iOS Simulator in Xcode 6.0.1 cannot reach internet

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Recently upgraded from Xcode 5 to Xcode 6. iOS Simulator cannot reach the internet now, even though just a few weeks ago it could with Xcode 5. Network settings have not changed since. What's really strange is that the internet will occasionally load when trying to hit an HTTPS site. Never loads with HTTP though.

I've already tried uninstalling, reinstalling, rebooting, removing devices from the Simulator, and re-adding them. Nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and I recently discovered a workaround fix (which won't for all sites). It seems that sites that can be accessed via https:// work perfectly fine. It's sites that use an un-secure protocol fail and I'm given the "Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding." message.